# Send email after SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I was trying to encapsule my application into three layers using entity framework as dao.
But I see it is impossible !!
So, I start using my DbSet in controller and doing something like:

```
var product = new Product();
product.Name = "product name";
db.Product.Add(product);
db.SaveChanges();
```

But now I dont have a BL layer, so, how can I set an observer to send an email after SaveChanges()?

Comment: Is there any submit changes callback parameter in the SaveChanges method? If so, your observer there.

Comment: @apoc29 Sorry, I did not understand.

Comment: To separate out my business logic layer from my data access layer with entity framework I use a repository pattern, Heres some info on one I wrote with some example 3-tier code: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2011/10/staticvoid-repository-pattern-nuget.html

Comment: I did try repository but I got lots of problems that I couldn't resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `saveChanegs` on your DBContext

```
 public class YourDbContext:DBContext
    {

       public override int SaveChanges(){
         foreach(var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
         {
           var entity = entry.Entity;
           if (entity is Entity1 or entity is Entity2)
           {
             //send email
           }
         }
         base.SaveChanges();
      }

   }
```

But it's not a good idea to do it in the DBContext because that is not what DbContext supposed to do. Sending email involves some business logic, it's better if you can have it in your business layer instead of data access logic.

Comment: But I would have to insert a 'if' for every new observer, wouldn't I?

Comment: What do you mean by `insert a 'if' for every new observer` ?

Comment: Assuming I have 20 classes but only 2 would send email after save. So I need to know in SaveChanges when I should send or not.